# How can get correct logger line number in the following context

Tags: java, logging, jboss, slf4j, appender

I have spend some time to figure out a sustainable way to filter out `ERROR` logs from my application in real time from `JBoss` server. With `Log4j` I can easily use `SocketAppender` and I configured it the way it will notify `ERROR` logs in real time. Unfortunately I can't do this with `JBoss AS 7`. I can't find a `SocketAppender` kind of implementation on it other than a `SMTPAppender`. So I came up with a way to solve this. Please take a look what I have done so far.

I wrote a kind of wrapper for `Logger`.

A sample class of my application

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyClass {
 private Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

 public void updateData(String data){
   logger.info("updating data with {} ",data);
   try {
        // do somthing
   }catch (Exception e){
        //something went wrong
       logger.error("update fail ",e);// I want to get this message real time
    }
 }
}
```

Now I thought of a way to get `ERROR` log.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyLogger {
    private Logger logger = null;

    private MyLogger() {
    }

    public static MyLogger getLogger(Class clazz) {
        MyLogger logger = new MyLogger();
        logger.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
        return logger;
    }

    public void info(String format, Object... arguments) {
        logger.info(format,arguments);
    }

    public void error(String format, Object... arguments) {
        // now i can send this message real time,
        // i am calling web service with error log by a new Thread 
        logger.error(format,arguments); // say line number 10
    }
}
```

`MyLogger` use as follows

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyLogger logger= MyLogger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void updateData(String data){
       logger.info("updating data with {} ",data);
       try {
            // do somthing
       }catch (Exception e){
            //something went wrong
           logger.error("update fail ",e); // say line number 14
       }
    }
}
```

At this point my requirement matched, But this create a new issue.

Following is the logger format configuration of `JBoss`

```
<pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%F:%L) (%t) %s%E%n"/>
```

Now `%F`-File name will become the `MyLogger` class. and `%L`- Line number will become the line number of `MyLogger` which leads inaccurate logs .

part of the sample log

```
(MyLogger.java : 10) // but this should be (MyClass.java : 14)
```

Now I have change this pattern to

```
<pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c:%L] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
```

This will almost work but `%c`-class name gives correct class as expected. But there is no way to get line number(correct line number).

After change logger paten what I get

```
(com.my.test.MyClass : 10) // but this should be (com.my.test.MyClass : 14)
```

Here are my questions.

1. Is there any log appender (`SocketAppender` or `JMSAppender`) work with `JBoss AS7` ?(found none working solution with Jboss AS 7)
2. Is there any better approach rather than this?
3. Is there any way to get correct Line number using this approach?

I have already asked an question in `JBossDeveloper`. But still there is no comment at least.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/249729

Any help highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a version equal or higher to JBoss 7.2 (EAP 6.1), you can use the **Log4j appenders** as custom handlers ([check this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4925)).

**eg**.

```xml
<custom-handler name="server" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender" module="org.apache.log4j">
  <level name="INFO"/>
  <formatter>
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <properties>
    <property name="RemoteHost" value="10.10.10.10"/>
    <property name="Port" value="1234"/>
    <property name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
    <property name="ReconnectionDelay" value="10000"/>
  </properties>
</custom-handler>
```

In other case the only one way to make it work in JBoss AS 7 is to develop a custom `java.util.logging.Handler` for `SocketAppender`.

Take a look in [Creating a custom logging handler in JBOSS as 7.1.0 Final](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLoggingHandlerInJBOSSAs710Final) and [Custom log handlers on 7.0.1](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CustomLogHandlersOn701) to create your custom log handler and then delegate them to `Log4jAppenderHandler`.

**eg (sample code):**

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation;
import org.jboss.logmanager.ExtLogRecord;
import org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.handlers.Log4jAppenderHandler;


public class SocketHandler extends Handler {

    private final Log4jAppenderHandler log4j = new Log4jAppenderHandler(new SocketAppender());

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        if (record == null) {
            return;
        }
        ExtLogRecord extRecord;
        if (record instanceof ExtLogRecord) {
            extRecord = (ExtLogRecord) record;
        } else {
            extRecord = ExtLogRecord.wrap(record);
        }
        if (isLoggable(record)) {
            LoggingEvent event = new LoggingEvent(extRecord.getLoggerClassName(),
                    Logger.getLogger(extRecord.getLoggerClassName()), extRecord.getMillis(),
                    Level.toLevel(extRecord.getLevel().toString()), extRecord.getFormattedMessage(),
                    extRecord.getThreadName(), extRecord.getThrown() == null ? null
                            : new ThrowableInformation(extRecord.getThrown()), extRecord.getNdc(),
                    new LocationInfo(new Throwable(), extRecord.getLoggerClassName()),
                    Collections.singletonMap("org.jboss.logmanager.record", extRecord));
            ((SyslogAppender) log4j.getAppender()).doAppend(event);
            flush();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        log4j.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        log4j.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilter(Filter filter) {
        log4j.setFilter(filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void setFormatter(Formatter formatter) {
        log4j.setFormatter(formatter);
    }

    public void setThreshold(String threshold) {
        ((SocketAppender) log4j.getAppender()).setThreshold(Level.toLevel(threshold));
    }

    public void setRemoteHost(String remoteHost) {
        ((SocketAppender) log4j.getAppender()).setRemoteHost(remoteHost);
    }

    public void setPort(String port) {
        try {  
            ((SocketAppender) log4j.getAppender()).setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));  
       } catch (Exception e) {}  
    }

    public void setReconnectionDelay(String reconnectionDelay) {
        try {  
            ((SocketAppender) log4j.getAppender()).setReconnectionDelay(Integer.parseInt(reconnectionDelay));  
       } catch (Exception e) {}  
    }

    public void setLocationInfo(String locationInfo) {
        try {  
            ((SocketAppender) log4j.getAppender()).setLocationInfo(Boolean.parseBoolean(locationInfo));  
       } catch (Exception e) {}  
    }

}
```

I think the best approach is this, so you would not have the logging implementation in your application.

See also: [Logging Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-customhandler)

I hope this help.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Check you do not have another version of log4j in the classpath, for example within the deploy (ear/war). You must use the version of log4j provided by the server. You can include a log4j dependecia from `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` or `WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in a war deployment. See http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-log/using-log4j-with-jboss-as-7-and-wildfly